# errno 22 when convering timestamp to date

Tags: python, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert the timestamp that I get from a ticker API to a human readable date.
My code is below; can you please help me identifying what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!!

```
import ccxt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone
import pytz
kraken = ccxt.kraken()
kraken_price = kraken.fetch_ticker('BTC/USD')
kraken_time = kraken_price['timestamp']
kraken_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(kraken_time)).strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')/1000
print(kraken_date)
print('Ask price for Kraken ${}'.format(kraken_price['ask']))
```

P.S. I am doing this in python

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `strftime()` gives string but you try to divide this string by `1000` ? it makes no sense and it should gives error. Maybe you should divide original value - `kraken_price['timestamp']/1000`

Comment: An `errno` value of 22 is `EINVAL`, "Invalid argument". But how do you know `errno` is 22? Your code doesn't examine `errno`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get `error 22` but when I run it then I get error

```
 ValueError: year 53354 is out of rang
```

because you have to divide original value

```
 kraken_time = kraken_price['timestamp']/1000
```

instead of dividing string which you get with `strftime()`

---

```
import ccxt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone
import pytz

kraken = ccxt.kraken()
kraken_price = kraken.fetch_ticker('BTC/USD')
kraken_time = kraken_price['timestamp']/1000
kraken_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(kraken_time)).strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(kraken_date)
print('Ask price for Kraken ${}'.format(kraken_price['ask']))
```

Result:

```
21-05-21 01:04:56
Ask price for Kraken $41232.8
```

---

**BTW:** as I remeber `error 22` can means problem with opening file and I don't see any file in your code. Or maybe it means some problem with downloading data from server. But you didn't show full error message so we can't check what makes problem.

Comment: Thanks Furas! Your solution worked. I had put the division in the wrong line! Much appreciated!!